# Analyzing underfitting and overfitting in Machine learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

below snapshot shows my code to get the mse and score of my model during  training and testing. From the code, could it be assumed:

1. Looking at the RandomForestRegressor, does it really show that the model is not performing well on the training set? cos the MSE is high on the training set and low on the test set. Can we say model is underfitting?

Likewise,

2. The XGBRegressor, i have low training error and high test error. Does this mean, the model is overfitting?

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rCWk.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots of code! See how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Both RF and XGB Regressors have issues with overfitting. Use cross-validation to resolve this issues. For example,

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=100)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# Create the parameter grid based on the results of random search 
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [80, 90, 100, 110],
    'max_features': [2, 3],
    'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5],
    'min_samples_split': [8, 10, 12],
    'n_estimators': [100, 200, 300, 1000]
}
# Create a based model
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
# Instantiate the grid search model
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)
# Fit the grid search to the data
grid_search.fit(X, y)
grid_search.best_params_
```